# Suppose that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and that $x > 1$, and that $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Does $x^{n}/n^{k}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Suppose that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and that $x > 1$, and that $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Does $x^{n}/n^{k}$ converge?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I started by considering the following series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{k}} = x + \frac{x^{2}}{2^{k}} + \frac{x^{3}}{3^{k}} + \ldots
\end{align*}

If such series converges, then its terms $a_{n} = x^{n}/n^{k}$ would converge to zero.

Unfortunately, when we apply the ratio test, one gets that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{k}}\times\frac{n^{k}}{x^{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{k}x = x > 1
\end{align*}

Thus it diverges and we cannot conclude that $a_{n}\to 0$.

It is also important to emphasize this problem happens before talking about series.

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: try taking the logarithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ration test told you the series diverges.

For fixed $ x>1$, we let
$$\gamma\in(1,x)$$
and
$$a_n=\frac{x^n}{n^k}$$

As you done,
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=x>\gamma$$
thus, for $ n $ great enough, let us say, for $ n> p$,

$$\frac{a_{p+1}}{a_p}\ge \gamma$$
$$\frac{a_{p+2}}{a_{p+1}}\ge \gamma$$
...

$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\ge \gamma$$
thus, by multiplication

$$a_n\ge a_p(\gamma)^{n-p}$$

then
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x^n}{n^k} \neq 0 \ \text{for any }k\in\mathbb{N}$$

Also your proof seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence diverges to $\infty$.

You can show this using L'Hopital $k$ times, for example.

A quicker, less precise way is to do $\log(\frac{x^n}{n^k})=n\log(x)-k\log(n).$ Since $n/\log(n)\rightarrow \infty$ we know that the subtraction must go to $\infty$.